# User input to edit Macro to adjust Excel Sort

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to figure out a way for a casual user to edit a Macro to sort data in Excel.

Basically, we have data that comes in with a column that contains the Division number responsible for that line item. Some supervisors might want to look at multiple job units on a regular basis.

The Macro works flawlessly but, to change what is shown, I have to go in and edit the associated line in the macro.

It would be amazing if there could be a button on the ribbon that opened a user input field to change the division numbers in the sort.

Here is the code (with a special thanks to urdearboy for this briilant work):

```
    Sub RowScrub()
Dim LRow As Long, I As Long
LRow = Range("B" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

For I = LRow To 3 Step -1
    If Range("B" & I).Value <> 807 And Range("B" & I).Value <> 812 And Range("B" & I).Value <> 820 And Range("B" & I).Value <> 840 And Range("B" & I).Value <> 846 And Range("B" & I).Value <> 849 And Range("B" & I).Value <> 861 And Range("B" & I).Value <> 862 And Range("B" & I).Value <> 864 And Range("B" & I).Value <> 865 And Range("B" & I).Value <> 868 Then
        Range("B" & I).EntireRow.Delete
    End If
Next I

End Sub
```

These 3-digit codes refer to the different offices within my organization. The offices assigned to me currently 807, 820, 840, 846... etc. These numbers can change and/or completely new numbers can be added.

I know that this line `And Range("B" & I).Value <> 812` can be edited or duplicated as needed. I would just like it if this could be changed by input box BUT only when necessary (may remain the same for weeks or months).

I think, to do what I need, a different Macro would be added, attached to a ribbon button and only used when changes to the "Row Scrub" macro is needed to be changed.

I have written a novel here and i don't even know if I am making sense. Please help.

Thanks.

Jeremy

Comment: For your "constant" values (807, 820, 840, etc) you can define them in several ways. Create a separate worksheet and assign the values to some cells, then name those cells. The user can edit the values and it will change the comparisons in your macro. Another way is to create a userform that asks for the values, supplying the last used value as a default. All of this you can connect to a ribbon button if desired.

Comment: Thank you PeterT.

I do not have access to the incoming files and they are "in a way" read only. So I don't think having a separate worksheet to pull the data from will work.

I am not knowledgeable about Userforms but I will start learning now. Is that something that can be saved and used across all workbooks?

Comment: look into Personal Workbooks. once you set it up, it is hidden but will open with excel and be able to store code so that it may be accessed no matter what other sheets/books you have open

Comment: if you build your userform in the personal workbook then yes, it would be available across all workbooks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I know that this doesn't do much to really improve on the original answer, but I think that it's worth including because taking on the task of creating your own userform can be difficult. I think that just editing the code, because you've said it might not change for long stretches of time, is a viable option but making that task a little bit more approachable with a reformat could be worthy of an 'answer', so here it is:

```
Sub RowScrub()

    Dim LRow As Long
    LRow = Range("B" & Rows.count).End(xlUp).row

    Dim i As Long
    Dim temp As Long

    For i = LRow To 3 Step -1
        temp = Range("B" & i).Value2
        If temp <> 807 _
           And temp <> 812 _
           And temp <> 820 _
           And temp <> 840 _
           And temp <> 846 _
           And temp <> 849 _
           And temp <> 861 _
           And temp <> 862 _
           And temp <> 864 _
           And temp <> 865 _
           And temp <> 868 Then
            Rows(i).EntireRow.Delete
        End If
    Next i

End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you. I do think that would work well. Easy to see what to change. Something I can write a quick procedure for. Love it.

Answer (score 1):

This code would require you to add new sheet, name it 'settings' and place your numbers in column 'A'.

```
Sub RowScrub()

Dim dict As Object
Set dict = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")

Dim wsSettings As Worksheet
Set wsSettings = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Settings")

With wsSettings

    j = 1
    Do While .Range("A" & j).Value <> ""
        dict.Add .Range("A" & j).Value, .Range("A" & j).Value
        j = j + 1
    Loop

End With

Dim LRow As Long, I As Long
LRow = Range("B" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

For I = LRow To 3 Step -1
    If dict(Range("B" & I).Value) <> Range("B" & I).Value Then
        Range("B" & I).EntireRow.Delete
    End If
Next I

End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply. We receive hundreds of these files a week. I don't think adding a sheet each time could be better than doing the work manually. I appreciate your time with this. I guess I was think a bit too outside the box.

Comment: You could easily move the settings part to a new workbook and refer to it in a personal workbook stored macro.